# Calculate mode of a input list

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm practising improving some code of mine. This is a function that calcualtes the most common number in an input list, and returns the lowest number if there are more than one number that occurs the same number of times

```
def mode(list):
    """ Calculates the mode of a list. Takes a list as argument"""
    current_count = 0
    a = max(list) + 1
    num_elements = [0]*a
    val = 0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        num_elements[list[i]] += 1
    for i in range(a):
        if num_elements[i] > current_count:
            current_count = num_elements[i]
            val = i
    return val
```

Unfortunately this function now has pseudo polynomial time complexity, and I want it to have an average time complexity of n. What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add unnecessary pseudo-polynomial time complexity by doing

```
a = max(list) + 1
for i in range(a):
   ...
```

and by thus making unnecessary iterations.
In order to keep the function linear in the input size you can create an association (i.e., dictionary *element->repetitions*) and then take the element of minimum value occurring the most.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def mode(l):
   # count occurrences (you could also use a Counter)
   d = defaultdict(int)
   for el in l:
      d[el]+=1
   # take the highest number of occurrences
   highest_occurrences = max(d.values())
   # return the element of minimum value with the highest number of occurrences
   return min(el for el in d if d[el]==highest_occurrences)
```

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is more convenient for this purpose

Comment: yes, as commented in the code it could be used to replace the 3 lines of code with `d = Counter(l)`.